# Displaying descending order status updates with avatar image and update image

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies for the length but I wanted to be clear.
I'm trying to make a website where people can update their status's (like Facebook). Just learning PHP. I have added a functionality whereby one can update their status(text only) or can update their status(text and upload a photo for that status). I have been able to do this but after updating, the difficulty is showing one's previous updates in the form of:

avatar pic - update text - update image(if image)

avatar pic - update text - default image(if update image not uploaded)

default avatar pic - update text - default image(if update image not uploaded)

with the latest updates first and then the rest in descending order.

If all updates for a user have update pics(ie. wid_updates.attached_picture_is not null, then I do not have a problem. If a user does not put up a pic update, then all hell breaks loose when returning previous updates.

Users table:

```
user_id, first_name, last_name, tel_no, address, username etc.
```

Wid_pdates table:

```
update_id, update_text, attached_picture_id, user_id, timestamp
```

Pictures table:

```
picture_id, picture_url, picture_thumb_url, user_id, avatar(bit)
```

The avatar bit is default 0 and set to 1 if it is the users avatar(profile) picture.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['UserSession'];
//query user avatar
mysql_select_db($database_connections, $connections);
$query_avatar_thumb = "SELECT picture_thumb_url FROM picture WHERE user_id='$user_id' AND avatar='1'";
$avatar_thumb_result = mysql_query($query_avatar_thumb) or die(mysql_error()); 
$avatar_thumb = mysql_fetch_assoc($avatar_thumb_result);

//query username
$query_user_info = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$user_info = mysql_query($query_user_info, $connections) or die(mysql_error());
$row_user_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_info);

//query update image
$query_wid_updates = "SELECT update_text, picture_thumb_url FROM wid_updates JOIN picture ON wid_updates.user_id = '$user_id' 
AND ((wid_updates.attached_picture_id = picture.picture_id) OR (wid_updates.attached_picture_id IS NULL)) ORDER BY wid_updates.update_id DESC";
$wid_updates = mysql_query($query_wid_updates, $connections) or die(mysql_error());
$row_wid_updates = mysql_fetch_assoc($wid_updates);
?>
```

If all updates have a picture, then everything is good. if one update does not have a picture that update is displayed the same number of times as the no. of pictures in the pictures table , each pic included. If there are 4 pics in pictures, the text update without image will be returned 4 times with each of the pics attached.

What is wrong? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you do the join (with the pictures table) on wid_updates.attached_picture_id = picture.picture_id OR wid_updates.attached_picture_id IS NULL

Just do a LEFT JOIN without the OR part. Something like:

```
SELECT update_text, picture_thumb_url FROM wid_updates 
LEFT JOIN picture 
ON wid_updates.attached_picture_id = picture.picture_id 
ORDER BY wid_updates.update_id DESC
```

Not sure why you also match the user_id in the join. But if you need that, add that to my query :)

Ah, ok, to just get a specific users updates with their pictures (picture_id will be NULL if no picture was attached) do it like this:

```
SELECT update_text, picture_thumb_url FROM wid_updates 
LEFT JOIN picture 
ON wid_updates.attached_picture_id = picture.picture_id 
WHERE wid_updates.user_id = '$user_id'
ORDER BY wid_updates.update_id DESC
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan Hållén for you reply.The reason I match user_id on the join is because the pictures table holds the pictures of other users. This is my profile.php page and I wanted a user to see only their past updates. On the homepage, they will see theirs and other users

Comment: I'd do that by adding a WHERE user_id = '$user_id' instead. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks again :) .Im alittle embarassed to tell you how long i have been struggling with this problem. Your solution worked like a charm. Much appreciation!!!

Comment: Now I've edited the answer. Feel free to flag it as a proper answer if it works for you :)

Comment: I have just done so. I have just started using join queries in php. My other projects required simpler queries. 1st problem solved, about 10 more to go